# PFQuery in Xcode won't return more than 12 results

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm trying to do a simple query of grabbing a few objects from a class I have on the Parse Data Browser in Xcode via Parse's SDK. My code is as follows:

```
- (void)getMoreProducts
{
    PFQuery *prodQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Products"];

    //restrict to 10 items
    [prodQuery setLimit:10];
    [prodQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:self
                                        selector:@selector(getCallback:error:)];
}
```

Then I have a separate callback method `- (void)getCallback:(NSArray )retrievedObjects error:(NSError )error`. The above was working with 10 objects.

I was toying around with grabbing 20 objects instead and it crashed. I can increase the limit to 12, but once I go 13 or above, I crash.

Here's the message I'm getting:

`-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1029b5b40`

The callback method (`- (void)getCallback:(NSArray )retrievedObjects error:(NSError )error`) is getting called, but it looks like retrievedObjects is nil when I step through the code debugging. And it throws the above error since I'm trying to call `isEqualToString` on something that's null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Tim

Comment: Is `error` populated?

Comment: I have a feeling that in Parse, your 13th object is nil or has a nil property.

Comment: Can you use the data browser to look at your objects and see if maybe one of the objects is missing some important property?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it turned out there was a null property in the 13th object.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, it turned out the 13th record had a null value that I was trying to use.  Thank you for the help!